# Search improvement: Clickable advanced search options

Tags: feature-request

Often when I'm searching StackOverflow I find myself wanting to narrow down the results to just questions, mostly to reduce the redundancy in the search results (multiple answers showing up to the same question).

I usually forget the search syntax for narrowing it down, or don't feel like typing it, so I click on the Advanced Search Options and copy pasta. Can this be made clickable, so that it toggles it as a option in the search form or adds/removes from the search box?

I realize that the sidebar gives examples, but popular filters (survey to determine? search logs?), ones with few/static options (type, status, infavorites:mine), or user defined options (favorite tags as on StackOverflow homepage) could be made clickable.

Comment: Personally, I don't even bother using the built-in search, I use [The Greatest Search Engine Ever Created](https://www.google.com/).

Comment: @Cupcake: that has the same drawbacks as SO's own -- too many irrelevant hits. Since SO knows what is a question and what's an answer, what's accepted and what not, and what tags are applied, its search engine could be made more powerful.

Comment: @Cupcake, yeah I usually try SO first, then if I don't like the results I go to Google.

Comment: You might be interested in my [Advanced Search Helper userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011)